# Cannot install packages with Ansible

Tags: ansible

The issue: When I try to install a package ansible does not proceed. The CLI just sits there idle.

SSH is cofigured to connect with out prompting for a password. I have created a user called "test" and my sudoers file has the following configuration:

```
test    ALL=(ALL)       NOPASSWD:ALL
```

Also in /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg

```
inventory      = /etc/ansible/hosts
#library        = /usr/share/my_modules/
remote_tmp     = $HOME/.ansible/tmp
pattern        = *
forks          = 5
poll_interval  = 15
sudo_user      = root
#ask_sudo_pass = True
#ask_pass      = True
transport      = smart
#remote_port = 22 module_lang = C
```

When as user "test" I do

```
yum install lynx
```

the package specified gets installed.
But if I do

```
ansible local -s -m shell -a 'yum install lynx'
```

Nothing happens.

I am not sure what is going on :(

Comment: [this is why the yum module exists](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/yum_module.html).

Comment: @Sam only become under hosts is enough. Something across the lines of: - hosts: <hosts_names> become: True tasks: - name: install lynx register: result `become` usually needs a bool if I'm not wrong, so the whole install will go under root privilege

Answer (score 3):

Try using the yum module instead:

```
ansible local -s -m yum -a 'name=lynx state=present'
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to say "yes" to yum:

Try this instead:

```
ansible local -s -m shell -a 'yum install lynx -y'
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be using either the `yum` module or even better, the `package` module which is OS generic.

On the other hand, you other option is the `raw` module which runs an SSH-dirty command against your nodes!

This is an example for using the `package` module in a *task*:

```
----
- hosts: <hosts_names>
  sudo: yes
  tasks:
  - name: install lynx
    register: result
    package: name=lynx state=latest
    become: yes
    become_user: root
    become_method: sudo
    ignore_errors: True
```

Using the above playbook, hopefully helps you to install you desired package and even if it did not do that, you'll be able to easy go through the `result` variable and see what's going wrong.

And of course before all these, you should've made sure that your YUM repository/ies work propeprly!